# New Site Constantly Reprompts for Credentials

Tags: site-collection, windows-authentication, https, credentials

I created a new site but when I try to access it none of my credentials work. I have given my self the correct permissions, but keeps re prompting me. This is a new site with https and a specific host header. Don't know if that helps at all.

Comment: is it new site collection in new webapp or exisitng web app ?

Comment: does it have proper AAM mappings in the central administration.

Answer (score 0):

follow and ensure the below steps:

1. make sure your account is not locked.
2. have proper Alternate access mappings established with correct host name in a defined zone.
3. make sure DNS record is available for the hostname. for trouble shooting purposes, you may try with a host file entry and see if it works.
4. if it is an extranet or internet site, make sure DNS record is propagating for that you may visit whatsmyip.com or any other public sites to verify the hostname.
5. verify if there are any log file entries related to permissions and authentications.
6. make sure the claims based authentication is enabled.
7. If you have access to Central Admin, go to Manage Web Applications, And highlight the web application, and go to user policy in the ribbon. You can add a Full Control Account in the pop up window. Alternatively, you could add an account in the Site Collection Administrators group in Web Applications.
8. If you are using Internet Explorer, add the site to your trusted sites list in the Internet Options, on the security tab. This will help stop repeated prompts for credentials once authenticated.
9. You may want to check that there is not a firewall blocking communication between the SharePoint servers and the Server responsible for Authentication. Check all server software firewalls are configured correctly, and any hardware firewalls configured to allow the traffic through as required. The firewall ports will depend on your setup. Please review a list of required ports here : http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/02/21/tcpip-ports-of-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 0):

Most credential prompts occurred for me while using Kerberos. If you are using Kerberos make sure your SPNs are configured correctly, making sure you have the following SPNs registered by the app pool account, making sure there are no duplicates.

Use [this guide](http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/09/26/the-first-kerberos-guide-for-sharepoint-2013-technicians/)

```
setspn -S HTTP/webapp.domain.com domain\appPoolAcct
setspn -S HTTP/webapp domain\appPoolAcct
```